# Reduce with andThen across functions of different types

Tags: scala

I want to programmatically compose several functions. If these functions are all of the same type, I can do the following:

```
def a(x: Int): Int = x+1
def b(y: Int): Int = y/2
def c(z: Int): Int = z*4
val f1 = (a _) andThen (b _) andThen (c _)
val f2 = List((a _), (b _), (c _)).reduce(_ andThen _)
```

At which point `f1` and `f2` are the same thing, and this compiles because the `List` that defines `f2` is a `List[Function1[Int,Int]]`

However, if I want to chain together multiple compatible functions with different types using the same basic reduce technique, I get an error.

```
def d(x: Double): Int = x.toInt
def e(y: Int): String = y.toString
def f(z: String): Double = z.toDouble*4

//Works fine
val f3 = (d _) andThen (e _) andThen (f _)

//Doesn't compile
val f4 = List((d _), (e _), (f _)).reduce(_ andThen _)
```

The second option doesn't compile because the list that defines `f4` is inferred as a `List[Function1[Any,Any]]`, but I can't figure out if theres a clean type-safe way to take an ordered collection of functions of the form `Function1[A,B],Function1[B,C],Function1[C,D],...,Function1[X,Y]` and glue them together as a `Function1[A,Y]` like this.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't believe that `andThen` can be convinced that it is in the right place in the list. To make this more clear, think of the two `andThen` operators in `f3` expression: the first `andThen` is a different operation than the second `andThen` because it takes different functors as its arguments. The chaining only really works because of the inference chaining. The `List()` construct completely bypasses all of that.

Comment: I think this can be done with shapeless' `HList`s. I'll try to play with it when I have time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two problems here. The first (as you've noted) is that the list has a single element type, which will be inferred to be the least upper bound of the types of the elements it contains, which in this case is the extremely boring and useless `String with Int with Double => Any`. Heterogeneous lists provide one way of addressing this part of the problem, as I'll show in a second.

The second problem is that the `_ andThen _` is insufficiently polymorphic (as Bob Dalgleish points out in a comment above). The argument to `reduce` will be a function with a concrete input type and a concrete output type, so even if we had a heterogeneous list, there's no way we could reduce it with a `Function` from the Scala standard library—we'd need a [polymorphic function value](http://www.chuusai.com/2012/04/27/shapeless-polymorphic-function-values-1/) instead.

Fortunately (if you really want to do this kind of thing in Scala), there's a great library called [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) that provides nice implementations of both heterogeneous lists and polymorphic functions. For example, you could write the following:

```
def d(x: Double): Int = x.toInt
def e(y: Int): String = y.toString
def f(z: String): Double = z.toDouble * 4

import shapeless._

object andThen extends Poly2 {
  implicit def functions[A, B, C] = at[A => B, B => C](_ andThen _)
}
```

And then:

```
scala> val andThenned = HList((d _), (e _), (f _)).reduceLeft(andThen)
andThenned: Double => Double = <function1>

scala> andThenned(13.0)
res0: Double = 52.0
```

I think this is pretty neat.

Comment: I like how you also separated the code and the example with 'and then' ;)

Comment: I did that on purpose, believe it or not! Thanks for noticing!

Comment: This is awesome - exactly what I was looking for. I definitely have some reading to do about polymorphic function values and shapeless.