# Apply a function to an object with generic type in Scala

Tags: scala, generics

I have this code

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

case class Data[T: ClassTag](list: List[T]) {

}

trait Transformation {
  type T
  type U
  def transform(data: Data[T]) : Data[U]
}

class FromInt2String extends Transformation {
  override type T = Int
  override type U = String

  override def transform(data: Data[T]) = new Data(List("1", "2", "3"))
}

class FromString2Int extends Transformation {
  override type T = String
  override type U = Int

  override def transform(data: Data[T]) = new Data(List(1, 2, 3))
}

object Test extends App {
  override def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val data = new Data(List(1, 2, 3))

    val int2String = new FromInt2String()
    val data2 = int2String.transform(data)

    val string2Int = new FromString2Int()
    val data3 = string2Int.transform(data2)


    val transformations = List(int2String, string2Int)
    val data4 = transformations.foldLeft(data)((data, transformation) => {
      transformation.transform(data)
    })
  }
}
```

The problem is in the foldLeft method. I can't do it because the type isn't compatible but I need to apply all the transforms in my initial object data

Any ideas how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: What about avoiding generics and using ad-hoc partial functions with raw `Data` type?

Comment: I need generics, it's a must

Comment: You can compose the `transform` functions using `compose`/`andThen` : `(new FromInt2String).transform _ andThen (new FromString2Int).transform _`. I am also not sure why `FromInt2String` is a class and not an object. You could also look into type classes, which may simplify your design.

Comment: I get this

`val compose = int2String.transform _ andThen string2Int.transform`

Then I can do this
`val data4 = compose(data)`

But I need to do it for all the transformations in my list

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it using [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22212061/reduce-with-andthen-across-functions-of-different-types)

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import shapeless._

object andThen extends Poly2 {
  implicit def functions[A, B, C] = at[A => B, B => C](_ andThen _)
}

case class Data[T: ClassTag](list: List[T]) {

}

trait Transformation {
  type T
  type U
  def transform(data: Data[T]) : Data[U]
}

class FromInt2String extends Transformation {
  override type T = Int
  override type U = String

  override def transform(data: Data[T]) = new Data(List("1s", "2s", "3s"))
}

class FromString2Int extends Transformation {
  override type T = String
  override type U = Int

  override def transform(data: Data[T]) = new Data(List(4, 5, 6))
}

object Test extends App {
  override def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val data = new Data(List(1, 2, 3))
    println(data)

    val int2String = new FromInt2String()
    val data2 = int2String.transform(data)
    println(data2)

    val string2Int = new FromString2Int()
    val data3 = string2Int.transform(data2)
    println(data3)


    val transformations = int2String.transform _ :: string2Int.transform _ :: HNil
    val functions = transformations.reduceLeft(andThen)
    val data4 = functions(data)
    println(data4)
  }
}
```

Thanks to all of you that help me